# How do Pokémon stats change when they evolve?

Tags: attributes, pokerole

I've recently discovered [Pokerole](http://pokeroleproject.wix.com/pokerole), A.K.A. the Pokemon Roleplaying Game, and am liking what I see. It avoids [the problems that I had with PTA and PTU](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64792/why-should-i-worry-about-non-violent-humans), lets mon of different levels go toe-to-toe without it being a *total* curb stomp, it's flexible and not too hard to GM, yet has enough mechanical detail and customisation to feel meaty... But it also seems omit important details of how to resolve Pokemon evolution.

There's one helpful note on page 62 explaining what happens if a Pokemon's attribute value is higher than it's new form's normal limit, but aside from that special case there's nothing describing exactly what happens to a Pokemon's stats when it evolves.

Take the Charmeleon, for instance. It's base Special attribute is 2. It's evolved form's base Special attribute is 3. I'm not sure how that's supposed to be realised in play; The note from page 62 suggested that a Pokemon keeps its attributes when evolving, but it seems odd that a newly-evolved Pokemon could end up with attributes below its species' minimum... Yet it *also* seems odd for a Pokemon to get a free increase to one of its attributes by evolving, when another pokemon of the same species might have increased that stat before evolving, and so never gotten that boost.

I've been reading the rulebook trying to work out what the designers intended, but I can't seem to find any clear advice. Hopefully I've just missed something. **Where can I find instructions on how to update a Pokemon's stats during evolution?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You don't update the stats during evolution.

Once you have a pokemon (capturing, buying, trading, adopting, ...), you can only increase it's attributes by using experience (p61).

The situation that you describe:

> but it seems odd that a newly-evolved Pokemon could end up with attributes below its species' minimum...

was something that they wanted to be possible (as mentioned in this [FAQ answer](http://pokerole-project.tumblr.com/post/127645372166/how-does-pokemon-evolution-work-exactly-is-there)).

The pokemon that are listed in the pokedex entries are at their "weakest" state (see the red sidebar on p78). So feel free to increase the stats if they encounter it in the wild.

Comment: Interestingly, this means that the advantages of evolution are increased attribute maximums and access to a new move list, but not improved attribute values as some players might expect. I'll have to pass that information on.